# How to set the sql results index value by desired column name in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I set the sql results  index  value by desired column name in mysql? For example

Table name: country

```
+-----------+----------------+--------------------+
|   id      |     code       |   name             |
+-----------+----------------+--------------------+
|    1      |       88       |   Bangladesh       |
+-----------+----------------+--------------------+
|    2      |      966       |   Saudi Arabia     |
+-----------+----------------+--------------------+
|    3      |      967       |   Yemen            |
+-----------+----------------+--------------------+
|    4      |      963       |   Syria            |
+-----------+----------------+--------------------+
|    5      |      249       |   Sudan            |
+-----------+----------------+--------------------+
```

create table query is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and insert data to table is as follows:

```
insert  into `country`(`id`,`code`,`name`) values (1,88,'Bangladesh'),
(2,966,'Saudi Arabia'),(3,967,'Yemen'),(4,963,'Syria'),(5,249,'Sudan');
```

In result will show like this way:

If I execute the following  query and my desired result as  bellow:

```
select code, name from country order by code ;
```

Desired result:

```
[88] => Array
    (
        [code] => 88,
        [name] =>  Bangladesh            
    )

[249] => Array
    (
        [code] => 249,
        [name] =>  Sudan            
    )

[963] => Array
    (
        [code] => 963,
        [name] => Syria
    )

[966] => Array
    (
        [code] => 966,
        [name] => Saudi Arabia
    )

[967] => Array
    (
        [code] => 967,
        [name] => Yemen
    )
```

I need the array keys will be the code by direct SQL query. Is it possible?

Comment: you need to do it with php. I think you can set keys for mysql response.

Comment: sql give only rows back, I don't think it can give arrays back

Comment: prepare multidimensional array in while(fetch records) loop

Comment: Some suggestions on your SQL. There are only 249 countries/dependencies in the world, so the 'id' field will never be more than 3 digits. It looks like your code field is the same. I suggest setting both to INT(4). The table will be smaller and easier to be compact with data aligned on 4 byte boundaries.

Comment: btw> I don't recognize your numeric codes for countries. These do not match the ISO 3166-1 numeric codes? If you are interested in standardizing the code and name field by international conventions, I have a lot of this type of information on my website: opengeocode.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very easy to do this using [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), its [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method and the build of the keys you need using the [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function, as described in these steps:

1. Connect to the DB using DSN, username and password.
2. Query the DB.
3. Manipulate the result.

The code may look something like this:

```
const DB_DSN = "mysql:host=mysql.hostname.com;dbname=yourdb;port=3306";
const DB_USERNAME = "username";
const DB_PASSWORD = "P4ssW0rd!";

try
{
    $db = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
    $results = $db->query("SELECT code, name FROM country ORDER BY code")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $results = array_column($results, null, "code");
}
catch ( PDOException $e )
{
    throw new Exception("An error occurred during the interaction with the database (" . DB_DSN . ").", 0, $e);
}

var_dump($results);
```

Which will give you exactly the output you desire.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple loop reading the results:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);

$array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[$row['code']] = $row;
}
```

Comment: @ Barmar, I know that with the help of a simple loop ( eg. for, froeach, while etc. ) in php I will get the desired result. But I want to get the desired result direct from mysql. As mysql don't return array so I think it is not possible from mysql which will give the output as Sorted array based on array value.

Comment: PDO has `PDO::fetchAll()`, which returns all the results at once. mysqli doesn't have this, you have to write a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,'test');


    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }else{

       $query = 'SELECT code, name FROM country ORDER BY code';
       $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
       $result = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);           
       $result = array_column($result, null, "code");
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
    }
```